# Multiple persistent errors IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I run `IntelliJ IDEA` version 2019.2.3 on a `Windows 10`. We use the same version at school. It works there, but not on my home laptop. I've set the environment and CMD shows the correct path of Java. The JDK 1.8 is also properly installed. Please , what could the problem be ?

[image: PersistentHashMap, Persistent EnumeratorBase, AbstractStateStorage]

[image: No problems in detecting JAVA]

Comment: have you followed this? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html

Comment: It probably doesn't like the users name with cyrillic.

Comment: @Alex, thank you ! I thought about that as well, but is it really the only solution to reinstall Windows just because IntelliJ can't cope with people's names ?

Comment: I agree with @Alex this might be something related to non-unicode characters in the path which is why Windows is confused.

Comment: @Reborn Yes, I got a reply from IntelliJ that this is "a non-unicode symbols in path" problem but they removed the request in the meantime.... With not a shadow of solution to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I want to thank everyone for taking the time to give a helping hand ! 
The answers I received via Support at Jet Brains crashed the app or made it unusable. The FAQ links they provide is a collection of vague workarounds. And, especially for someone that is a total beginner and *has no guidance in editing non-destructively*,  it won't work.

I would also like to post *the only solution* that worked on the Cyrillic issue with IntelliJ Idea, since I know other people have had it as well and I hope it will be useful for others in the future. This came from my teacher at Link Academy Bucharest, Mr. Bogdan Posa.

The actual thing that needs to be modified is the existent file called ***idea.properties***, found in the BIN folder within the Idea installation folder. This only worked after I had re-installed Idea in a different place than "C:/Users/Cyrillic username/" which Idea was picking by default to install itself. So it will be something like C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.3/bin. The idea.properties file can also be opened with Notepad to avoid crashing Idea (happened many times).  Within the text editor, find and edit the value of idea.config.path, removing the comment and writing the new  location/path of the Idea installation folder. Windows might not allow you to save the edited idea.properties file in that original location and it might ask if you want to save it in the Documents folder instead. Just say yes, save it there and then copy/paste it back to the Bin folder, it will accept it. After this, you will have to open Idea with "right-click open as Administrator". Apparently, as long as there still is a path containing Cyrillics in a username, Idea will not run your project so if you can't avoid it, just play along and Run as Admin when opening Idea. That's how it NOW WORKS for me, after several re-installing and changing properties, environments and every damn thing. I was close to hugging ECLIPSE.... :) Hope this helps, Cyrillic users !

Answer (score 0):

No, not at all. This is a kind of wird exception. 
You can change the config location of intelliJ.,

This can be done in:

IntelliJ Menu: Help | Edit Custom Properties…
Then it will create a file under: IDE_HOME\bin\idea.properties

Example of the configs:

```
idea.config.path=c:/work/idea/config
idea.system.path=c:/work/idea/system
idea.plugins.path=c:/work/idea/plugins
```

More info: 
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage

Comment: I struggled with that, ended up crashing Idea. Uninstalled , rebooted and reinstalled it several times. Even changed my Admin username in Latin characters and the newly installed Idea STILL retains the path with cyrillic characters !!! How can that be ?!?

Comment: The old config may be picked up some where.. Here: they mention that also these folders should be removed. 

Example:
C:\Users\JohnS\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\config 
C:\Users\JohnS\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system 

If that did not work., i would suggest reinstall with Toolbox method which they recommend. 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installation-guide.html#